# How to create a simple tile in wpf?

Tags: wpf, tile

How to create a simple tile in WPF, is there a native control? or it is absolutely necessary to install a package via nuget?

I saw that there was control: Tile Control but I can not find it in the toolbox

Thanks in advance

Comment: First Googel result: [Tiles for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/creating-tiles)?

Comment: Thanks but I do not use the UWP but Application WPF.

Comment: I found this post but I can not find this control in my toolbox 
 https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/11541/Controls-and-Libraries/Layout-Management/Tile-and-Layout/Tile-Layout-Control

Comment: Oh you want to build your own tile layout and not use the windows ones...You know that `DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl` is an 3rd party library you need to [buy](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/) to use the tile features shown on that site, it has nothing to do with Microsoft or the included controls.

Comment: There is no free equivalent?

Comment: Just have a look tile documentation from mahapps.metro : http://mahapps.com/controls/tile.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in `Tile` control available in WPF.

You will have to create a custom yourself or use a third-party control.

There are free open-source options available, like for example the `mahapps.metro` `Tile` control: http://mahapps.com/controls/tile.html. It does of course require you to install `mahapps.metro` (preferably using `NuGet`) though: http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

Comment: there's also this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290587/A-WPF-TileView-Control) from codeproject

Answer (score 0):

add these namespace in a page or window `xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"`.By this,we can use tile in mahapps

```
<mah:Tile ToolTip="Tile" Width="90" Height="50"  Click="GetTileDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="22" >
   <TextBlock Text="Text" ></TextBlock></mah:Tile>
```